# How to fix 'web page loaded but not show' in unity with uniwebview 3.4.0?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, uiwebview

I used `UniWebView` 3.4.0 to show web page on Unity for `iOS` platform. But the web page didn't show up when it loaded successfully.Please tell me why.

```cs
    private UniWebView m_view;
    public void Open(string url, Transform menuBar, Action<string> cb)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) return;
        m_view = GetWebView();

        m_view.SetZoomEnabled(true);
        m_onLoaded = cb;
        m_view.Load(url, true);

        m_view.Show();
    }

    private UniWebView GetWebView()
    {
        var webview = Game.Instance.transform.GetChild<UniWebView>();
        if (webview == null)
        {
            var temp = new GameObject("WebView");
            webview = temp.AddComponent<UniWebView>();
            temp.transform.SetParent(Game.Instance.transform);
            webview.OnPageFinished += OnLoaded;
            webview.OnShouldClose += OnClose;
        }
        return webview;
    }

        private void OnLoaded(UniWebView webView, int statusCode, string url)
    {
        if (m_onLoaded != null) m_onLoaded(statusCode.ToString());
                webView.Show();
    }
```

I called `Open()` with a valid url.When Unity executed `OnLoaded()`, I could see statusCode is 200 but the web page didn't show up! I made sure that fullScreen of `UniWebView` is true by defining macro `UNITY_IOS` in `UniWebView.cs` . Please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it ?